# Functions don't work with multiple jQuery files in PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery

This would be the first time I use multiple jQuery files with different functions. But unfortunately there's a problem. This is my code:

```
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <link href="styles/glDatePicker.default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="js/glDatePicker.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.txt').glDatePicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
            });
        });
    </script>
```

This code is working because the calendar is showing, but when I included this other jQuery file the above function will not work anymore. But just alerting the "ok" message.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myPhoto() {
        alert('ok');
    }
</script>
```

If I remove this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

The code for first function works but the second does not. How can I get both to work?

Comment: jquery conflict.try to debug your app in firebug.

Comment: where do you call your myPhoto()?

Comment: The first function would be just inputting date from a datepicker then the myPhoto() function is triggered when a button was hit for uploading picutre.

Comment: Where i will try this firebug? @Sir Mahmood Rehman

Comment: right click on website and goto inpect element normally last item in window.then goto console mode there you will see errors.

Comment: Firebug is an add-on for Firefox. Chrome has a built in console as well.

Comment: Are you sure you need multiple versions of jQuery?

Comment: Try using     var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

Comment: just remove the `scripts/jquery.min.js`, you cannot load more than one version of jQuery

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'glDatePicker' - This was the error. This 'glDatePicker' was from the first version of Jquery i have which i think have a conflict with other version of jquery.

Comment: Yes @Sir zan , i do need this versions of jquery in order to first: have a datepicker and secondly: to upload picture.

Comment: if i remove "scripts/jquery.min.js" then function for uploading of pictures will not work.

Comment: all this script are included in the same php file or different files? ? you should add more information to get a good answer, your first code show that you include your script inside <head/>  in a php file, so what about the second code, where you include it ?

Comment: All the scripts are in the same php file sir @medBo.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to include all js file in the head like this :

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.form.js"></script>
    <link href="styles/glDatePicker.default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="js/glDatePicker.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.txt').glDatePicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
            });
        });
    </script>
```

i don't think this line `<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>` is needed, so try to remove it like i do in above ;)